# How to filter a sharepoint list

Tags: web-part, filter, splist

I have a custom list called expenses.  The list has fields such as user,date,amount etc.

I want the user to be able to filter this list by amount e.g. add a dropdown above the list with a search button and these items 
'Below 10', 
'Above 10',
'Above 50 etc'

This has to be done in visual studio as i am creating a web template.

How would i go about implementing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in several ways.

One of them would be to declaratively create a List Definition which contains a View with the filters that you need (you can even make it the default view if required).

Here's a walkthrough on creating list definitions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg276355.aspx

Another option would be to programmatically create the View in a new or existing list.
Here's an example on how to add a View to a list: http://sarangasl.blogspot.com.ar/2009/12/create-sharepoint-list-view.html

As I mentioned, you can either programmatically create the list and add the view, or you can just get an existing list an add the view.